# adding facebook messenger button on ibm node-red

Tags: json, curl, ibm-watson, chatbot, watson-conversation

We have created a ibm watson conversation workspace and fb messenger on ibm node-red, now we'd like to add facebook messenger buttons on ibm node-red, so we are able to see some link buttons and pictures on facebook messenger when we ask "recommending some famous buildings", any sample codes or document would be appreciated

Comment: follow the official facebook messenger doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/button  ,  we paste that curl command and hit the following error:
{"error":{"message":"(#100) The URL provided is not whitelisted for messenger extensions","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"e                   rror_subcode":2018062,"fbtrace_id":"AtdsOh0jXSU"}}

Answer (score 0):

So, as you can see on the [Official Facebook Developer website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/button), you need to use some custom code.

So in your POST request, you need to use:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient":{
    "id":"<PSID>"
  },
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"template",
      "payload":{
        "template_type":"button",
        "text":"What do you want to do next?",
        "buttons":[
          {
            "type":"web_url",
            "url":"https://www.messenger.com",
            "title":"Visit Messenger"
          },
          {
            ...
          },
          {...}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

This example is using cURL but you can use any language that supports HTTP requests. *In Node-red you can use the function button to add some custom codes like my example above.*

- Tutorial on how you can use [buttons on Facebook Messenger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2JIIMIfuj4).
- Github repository working with IBM Watson Conversation and Facebook Messenger, have one example for using buttons in this [link](https://github.com/cyrillebenoit/conversationMaster/blob/master/buttons.js).